# Set log file permissions for gunicorn process

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a gunicorn service managed by systemd on a Debian Buster server. Here is the `/etc/system.d/system/my_site` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for my site
Requires=my_site.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
User=someuser
Group=somegroup
WorkingDirectory=/home/soemuser/my_site/
ExecStart=/home/someuser/my_site_env/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.my_site.sock --workers 2 --log-file /var/log/my_site.log my_site.wsgi:application
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This logs some gunicorn and my_site output to `/var/log/my_site.log`, great! The problem is that the log file is created with the following permissions: `-rw-rw-rw- root root`. Not so good.

**How can I change the ownership and permissions on the created log file?**

Unless I missed something there is nothing about it in the gunicorn doc.

Answer (score 0):

Add your user to the `www-data` group and set the group to `www-data`.

```
User=user
Group=www-data
```

and try to replace

```
--log-file /some/path
```

with

```
--access-logfile
```

Comment: Well... the reason I have created `someuser` is that user `www-data` can do many things that gunicorn should not be able to touch. Adding my user to the `www-data` group would partly defeat my tentative to secure the whole thing.

Comment: then change the permission of the directory according to your user and group. sudo chown -R someuser:somegroup /path/to/directory. and each user and group is only allowed to do what you allow, in theory using somegroup or www-data is the same.